# Creating an array of objects from a class in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to create an array of 20 candidates from my `Candidate` class. So far, this is what I have:

```
Candidate candidate0 = new Candidate();
Candidate candidate1 = new Candidate();
Candidate candidate2 = new Candidate();
Candidate candidate3 = new Candidate();
...
Candidate candidate19 = new Candidate(); 

Candidate[] candidates = new Candidate[20];
candidates[0] = candidate0;
candidates[1] = candidate1;
candidates[2] = candidate2;
candidates[3] = candidate3;
...
candidates[19] = candidate19;
```

I know this is not the correct or 'best' way to do this. What would be the best way?

Comment: Use a loop, `for(int i=0;i<candidates.Length;i++){candidates[i] = new Candidate();}`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a [for loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ch45axte.aspx) :

```
int candidateLength = 20 ; 

Candidate[] candidates = new Candidate[candidateLength ];

for(int i=0 ; i<candidates.Length ; i++)
{
   candidates[i] = new Candidate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adam - you'd be subjectively better off using a list for this along the lines of:

```
List<Candidate> canditateList = new List<Candidate>();

// MaxLength is a const defined somewhere earlier perhaps
for(int i=0 ;i<MaxLength;i++){
  canditateList.Add(new Candidate(){... properties here});
}

// etc, etc.
```

You could then factor this out to an array if required using:

```
var candidateArray = canditateList.ToArray();
```

Just my initial thoughts, tho you may of course have a good reason for wishing to use an array from the start, my premise is that I would go with a list and party on that for various extracted flavours.

Comment: Thanks, seems so obvious now haha